# Como centralizar texto usando print document c#?

Tags: c#, impressão

Estou fazendo uma impressão e gostaria de centralizar o textoestou usando esse código no `printpage`

```
 e.Graphics.DrawString("bla bla bla bla",
                      FontTitulo,
                      brush,
                      e.MarginBounds);
```

Como faço para centralizar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Douglas,
Há varias formas de centralizar o texto, uma delas é obtendo o retângulo dos limites da página.

```
string text1 = "Este texto será centralizado no TOPO";
            using (Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point))
            {

                //O string format serve para formatar strings
                //quanto a seu alinhamento e o proprio alinhamento da linha
                StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();

                sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

                SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black);

                //Captura todo o retângulo dos limites da página
                System.Drawing.RectangleF rect = e.PageBounds;

                //Aumenta a coordenada de localização Y
                rect.Y += 50;

                //Desenhar texto centralizado
                e.Graphics.DrawString(text1, font1, drawBrush, rect, sf);

            }
```

Como se trata de um **PrintDocument** a propriedade *PageBounds* permite capturar o retângulo associado ao limite da página. Aumentei o valor da coordenada **Y** para ficar "parecido" com um Título.

Comment: deu certinho vlw